# Is it possible to see the pipeline definition of a MongoDB View?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have created MongoDB view few days ago. Now I want to take a look at it again. (Query that I have written to create view). Is it possible?

I tried using collmod function `db.runCommand( { collMod: 'viewName'})` but it is just returning 'Ok' as response.

I have been searching on it from hours but no luck.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `db.getCollectionInfos()` method. See the [manual for the method](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getCollectionInfos/) for a detailed explanation.

For example:

```
> db.createView('testview', 'test', {$project: {a:1, b:1}})

> db.getCollectionInfos({name:'testview'})
[
  {
    "name": "testview",
    "type": "view",
    "options": {
      "viewOn": "test",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$project": {
            "a": 1,
            "b": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "info": {
      "readOnly": true
    }
  }
]
```

The view definition is shown under the `pipeline` field.

Note that you can also filter by `type: 'view'` to display the definition of all the views in the database:

```
> db.getCollectionInfos({type:'view'})
[
  {
    "name": "testview",
    "type": "view",
    "options": {
      "viewOn": "test",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$project": {
            "a": 1,
            "b": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "info": {
      "readOnly": true
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "testview2",
    "type": "view",
    "options": {
      "viewOn": "test",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "count": {
              "$sum": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "info": {
      "readOnly": true
    }
  }
]
```